# Cancellation in Coroutines and Okhttp

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

So I'm playing around using Coroutines and Okhttp to connect a websocket.

## What I've done

```
// initialise okhttp
fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(RetryInterceptor())
            .build()
}

// RetryInterceptor.kt
class RetryInterceptor : Interceptor {

    companion object {
        private const val RETRIES_LIMIT = 4
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        var retries = 0

        var response: Response?
        response = sendRequest(chain, request)

        while (response == null && retries <= RETRIES_LIMIT) {
            retries++
            val sleepTimer = 2.toDouble().pow(retries.toDouble())
            Log.d("OkhttpClient", "Connection failed, retry in ${sleepTimer}s")
            Thread.sleep(sleepTimer.toLong() * 1000)
            response = sendRequest(chain, request)
        }

        return response ?: Response.Builder()
            .request(request)
            .code(400)
            .build()
    }

    private fun sendRequest(chain: Interceptor.Chain, request: Request): Response? {
        val response: Response
        return try {
            response = chain.proceed(request)
            if (!response.isSuccessful) null else response
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            null
        }
    }
}

// define a exception handler
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        when (throwable) {
            is CancellationException -> {
                // cancel the socket connection here
                Log.d("CancellationException", "cancelled")
            }
            else -> onRegisterError(
                throwable.localizedMessage ?: "Coroutine Error"
            )

        }
    }

// Then inside ViewModel, fire up the okhttp client
val viewModelScopeJob = viewModelScope.launch(context = handler) {

            val someOtherJob = otherContext.launch {
                // launch suspend fun connectSocket()
            }

        }
// Then call cancel inside ViewModel like this:
viewModelScopeJob.cancel()
```

## Problem

`viewModelScopeJob` is a parent job, when the `cancel()` is being called, it should cancel its child-jobs and invoke the `CancellationException`, however it doesn't.

## Question

So the coroutine job will not be cancelled because of `Thread.sleep()` inside interceptor is not cooperative.

My questions is: given `RetryInterceptor` is located in a separate class, I'm not be able to use methods like `delay()`, how should I change my code in order to cancel the retry when `viewModelScopeJob.cancel()` is called?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two fixes.

First, register a coroutine cancelation listener that cancels the OkHttp call. You can see an example of this in [Retrofit’s coroutine integration](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/bf9f11430de52b13f2f3f1aa2be4b64d6471a46d/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt).

```
continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
  cancel()
}
```

Next, you need to interrupt the thread sleep when the call is canceled. One way to handle this is with an [EventListener](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-event-listener/canceled/). Override cancel to interrupt the OkHttp thread. You can save a reference to that thread with `Thread.currentThread()` in `callStart()`. You should also override `callEnd()` and `callFailed()` to clear that saved reference.

The [Events](https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/) page has more information on how to register an event listener factory so that each call gets its own `EventListener` instance.

Comment: it seems `EventListener` will not get called when using okhttp for websocket connections?

Comment: So it will indeed ignore `EventListener`, because in `RealWebSocket.kt` of okhttp:  `fun connect(client: OkHttpClient)` will start a websocket client with `EventListener.NONE`

Comment: Ah, I’m sorry, I missed the Web Socket part of your original post.